# What is the best way to get the keys of IreliableDictionary

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I basically have  a name value collection but the collections are pretty big and i can see all the enumerableasynch methods fetch the name value pairs.

A second collection of just keys could possible do this if there is no better way but even this is a bit tricky since there is no set or collection .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate the keys using [IReliableDictionary2.CreateKeyEnumerableAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.collections.ireliabledictionary2-2.createkeyenumerableasync?view=azure-dotnet).